# Help Regarding SQL injection

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-injection

Please help me to prevent my data from SQL injection.
I have replaced ' with '' (single quote with 2 quote) while doing any operation on sql server.
Please tell me what all i need to do , to prevent my application from SQL injection. my application is in asp.net 2.0

i will use parameterized queries but what about my old projects.. i mean what about where i have written a string query and sending it to sql server as a commandtext.

Please tell me can any one insert sql injection even i have replaced ' with ''?

Comment: Replacing quotes is error-prone and does *not* protect you. There are many ways to exploit SQL code, and that only takes care of one of them. Fortunately, it’s easy to stop SQL injection: use parameterized queries. Then you don’t have to replace quotes or escape your SQL queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best you can do is to use parameterized queries, if the language/framework supports it.

EDIT: asp.net can handle it. Use [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)

An example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) -

```
private static void UpdateDemographics(Int32 customerID,
    string demoXml, string connectionString)
{
    // Update the demographics for a store, which is stored 
    // in an xml column. 
    string commandText = "UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics "
        + "WHERE CustomerID = @ID;";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

        // Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics.
        // SQL Server will implicitly convert strings into XML.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Parametrized queries are indeed the way to go, solving sql injection problems, date problems, and even increasing performance in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, i will use parameterized queries but what about my old projects.. i mean what about where i have written a string query and sending it to sql server as a command

Comment: Working with ADO .Net directly is a questionable practice these days.

Comment: @Svetlozar: I've recalculated your reputation, as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cleaning up the SQL manually, you should be using a library to access SQL.

Do not build up query string manually and if you need to pass parameters through, use parameterized queries and stored procedures.

See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210512233418/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.shtml) example in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain, but I don't think there's any quick easy way to protect your old projects from SQL injection attacks.

I think your best bet would probably be to actually modify the data access code in your old projects to use parameterised queries.

Or, you could do as Oded suggests and re-write your old projects using a library.